# Sliding div into view, but in middle of screen

Tags: jquery, slide

Were all familiar with using jQuery and hidden divs to slide divs into view from off screen, but is there a concept of sliding a div into view in the middle of a screen?

For example, if I click on a navigation item in a navbar - not at the edge of the screen - then having a subnav slide into view immediately below or next to it.

I have a feeling I've seen this, but I can't seem to find out how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you Google it?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, can you provide more details? Is the navigation vertical or horizontal?

Comment: I actually did Google it, but, if it's out there, I'm searching on the wrong terms, since I'm not getting anything useful. I'm not sure yet of the orientation of the navigation. I'm still in the concept stage. I would think, though, that it almost wouldn't matter. What would be the difference?

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEMoNG

Comment: Thank you, but no. You see how that starts outside the viewport and comes in. I'm looking for something that would have the appearance of sliding out from behind the navigation bar, not slide in from off-screen.